# Python - adding specific inputs to a variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my program, the user will enter more than one code in the "AB123" format. Based on the entered codes, I have to filter out those that start with the letters "AB" and end with the numbers "00". I have to print and count their number separately from the bulk of all codes, how can this be done?

My current code is:

```
def main():
    code = input("Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AB123':")
    print("Your codes are:", code)
    pCodes = None

    if len(code) == 5 and code.startswith('AB') and code.endswith('00'):
        pCodes = code.startswith('AB') and code.endswith('00')
        print("Ok, here are your prioritized codes", pCodes)
    else:
        print("There are no codes with 'AB' letters and '00' digits at the end!")

main()
```

I tried to integrate a new variable `pCodes` to assign all codes with letters "AB" and digits "00" but it's not working as planned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop, and add brackets in order for it to be a list comprehension:

```
def main():
    code = input("Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AB123':")
    print("Your codes are:", code)
    codes = [c for c in code.split() if len(c) == 5 and c[:2] == 'AB' and c[-2:] == '00']  
    if codes:
        print("Ok, here are your prioritized codes", codes)
    else:
        print("There are no codes with 'AB' letters and '00' digits at the end!")


main()
```

Input:

```
Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AB123':AB100 UI812 GS901 AB300
```

Output

```
Your codes are: AB100 UI812 GS901 AB300
Ok, here are your prioritized codes ['AB100', 'AB300']
```